# Escape from ElementRef to avoid XSS attacks vs overload with checking Boolean values with ngClass

Tags: angular

I feel a little lost in this aspect. On the one hand we must avoid access to the DOM using ElementRef to avoid XSS injection attacks. But on the other hand the use of [ngClass] makes continuous checks of boolean values or associated functions which I understand can overload the page.

What role does ngChanges use here? **Is there a way for ngClass checks to be performed only when the value of an @Input has change** using ngOnChanges () ?

What are best practices here? Thanks a lot in advance

I was trying with this example where I have a component with an input I pass the value from parent. Then the idea is to do some parts of child component affected by using ngClass and depending of the value of the input.:

PARENT

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

    selector: 'spapp',

    template: `
    <init [stateOpenClose]="stateOpenCloseValue"></init>
    <button (click) = "toggleStateOpenCloseValue()">ToggleValue</button>
    <a routerLink="/abhome" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    stateOpenCloseValue: string = 'open';

    constructor() {

    }
    toggleStateOpenCloseValue() {

        this.stateOpenCloseValue = (this.stateOpenCloseValue === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open');
        console.log(this.stateOpenCloseValue);
    }

}
```

CHILD

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'init',
    styleUrls: ['app/modules/init/init.component.css'],


    template: 
` 

<header>
    <section id="section-init">
        <div class="container-fluid" >
            <div id="topBox" class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 align-self-end">
                    <h1>TITLE</h1>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="botBox" class="row" >
                <div class="col-xs-12 align-self-top">
                    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</header>

`


})
export class InitComponent {
    @Input('stateOpenClose') stateOpenClose:string;
    constructor() { 


    }
    ngOnChanges() {
        console.log(this.stateOpenClose);
    }
}
```

Comment: tell whats exactly needed! is it a opinion or a suggestion u r asking

Comment: I need to know if there is a way for ngClass checks to be performed only when the value of an @Input has change.

Comment: yes can be done. share the code to help further

Comment: Done. Thank you very much. I need child component template using [ngClass] but only doing comprobation when the Input changes.

Comment: where you want to add the ngClass to child? share the init html

Comment: Edited. For example one of the rows I have identified as #topBox or #botBox

Comment: Your code doesn't even show the use of `ngClass`. If you bind to a field instead of a function, binding to `ngClass` won't overload your page, in fact, it won't hurt performance at all.

Comment: You can use an object, a list of strings, and a string. If you have a boolean value you need to use `[class.someclass]="someBoolean"`. Angular is extremely efficient with checking fields for changes. You can further optimize and limit the rate of change detection using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. You can further optimize by using observables with the `| async` pipe, Angular will still check if the returned observable has changed, therefore you can't totally avoid change detection. If this bothers you, Angular is probably not the right framework for you.

Comment: If it would know in advance when the value has changed, it wouldn't need change detection at all. It has to do change detection to know if it has changed, therefore what you ask for doesn't exist. The closest are observables, but as mentioned Angular still checks if the observable is a different one than when it last checked.

Comment: It helped so much. I still lack concepts, I'm still in learning process. Can we say then as good practice do not bind to functions unless it is extremely necessary?
I will read more about ChangeDetectionStrategy and using | async pipe in observables. Anyways it helps to know more the concept. Thank you so much, really apreciated.

Comment: Yes, binding to functions should be avoided.